# Interaction plot using ggplot2 for hierarchical model (lmerMod) with statistical significance highlighting

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, marginal-effects

I am working with a hierarchical model (lmerMod) that has an outcome and two categorical variables, `cat1` and `cat2`. I want to make an interaction plot using `ggplot2::` that visualizes the model coefficients and takes into account two specific complexities:

Pairwise comparisons: I need to compare the coefficients for each level of `cat2` (Control, T1, T2, T3) against each other within each level of `cat1` (1 and 2).
Statistical significance: I want to highlight the statistical significance of these comparisons using asterisks or some similar notation. Examples are `ggsignif` or `ggpval` packages, or `ggpubr::stat_compare_means()` function.

### Requirements:

- The geometry should be `pointrange`.
- `cat1` should be on the x-axis.
- `cat2` should define the color aesthetic.
- I want to use the `lmerTest` package for model fitting (to get correct p-values).

### Challenges:

- Using `ggeffects::hypothesis_test()` takes a very long time for large datasets (N=46,000, G1=4,000, G2=40).
- I struggle with `ggplot` solutions for having brackets (significance stars can be places with `geom_text()` and `ifelse()` I guess)

### Reproducible Example:

Here's a simple R example using a toy dataset:

```
# Load required packages
library(lmerTest)
library(ggplot2)

# Create toy data
set.seed(123)
N <- 1000  # Increased sample size
G1 <- 20   # Increased number of levels for G1
G2 <- 10   # Increased number of levels for G2

df <- data.frame(
  outcome = rnorm(N),
  cat1 = factor(rep(1:2, each = N / 2)),
  cat2 = factor(rep(c("Control", "T1", "T2", "T3"), each = N / 4)),
  G1 = factor(rep(1:G1, each = N / G1)),
  G2 = factor(rep(1:G2, each = N / G2))
) 

# Fit the hierarchical model
fit <- lmerTest::lmer(outcome ~ cat1 * cat2 + (1|G1) + (1|G2), data = df)
summary(fit)

# Attempt to make the plot
interactions::cat_plot(model = fit, pred = cat1, modx = cat2, 
                       interval.geom = "linerange", colors = "Set1")
# ... (I want significance stars and brackets connecting the coefficients: this is where I am stuck)
```

[image: Categorical by categorical interaction without significant differences]

Answer (score 0):

First, note that there are two problems with your data generation, when fitting the model

> fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 4 columns / coefficients

> boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')

The first issue arises because there is perfect multicollinearity in the predictors. This means one or more predictors can be perfectly predicted using other predictors in the model. When this happens, the matrix of predictors (often called the design matrix) cannot be inverted, and the model coefficients cannot be uniquely estimated.

The second is likely due to there being too little variation in one of the random effects. for the sake of this answer I will just omit the random effect for `G2`. So, hopefully, I think we can achieve what you want with the following code:

```
library(lmerTest)
library(ggplot2)
library(effects)

# Create toy data
set.seed(123)
N <- 1000
G1 <- 20
G2 <- 10

df <- data.frame(
  outcome = rnorm(N),
  cat1 = factor(rep(1:2, each = N / 2)),
  cat2 = factor(sample(c("Control", "T1", "T2", "T3"), N, replace = TRUE)), # Shuffle the cat2 levels randomly
  G1 = factor(rep(1:G1, each = N / G1)),
  G2 = factor(rep(1:G2, each = N / G2))
)

# Fit the hierarchical model with interaction
fit <- lmerTest::lmer(outcome ~ cat1 * cat2 + (1|G1) + (1|G2), data = df)

# Extract effects of interaction
eff <- effect("cat1:cat2", fit)

# Convert effect object to dataframe for plotting
eff_df <- as.data.frame(eff)

# Rename columns for ease of use
names(eff_df) <- c("cat1", "cat2", "fit", "lower", "upper")

# Visualization using ggplot2
ggplot(eff_df, aes(x = cat1, y = fit, color = cat2, group = cat2)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = cat2), size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = cat2)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2) +
  labs(y = "Predicted Outcome", title = "Interaction Effect of cat1 and cat2") +
  theme_minimal()
```

which generates the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The data generation was just meant to produce a reproducible example. Your visualization does show these changes, but not the significance. In the example above was trying to add brackets with asterisks to highlight whether, e.g., there is a statistically significance increase from Cat2=="Control" to Cat2=="T1" when cat1==1. An example is in the ggsignif intro:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/vignettes/intro.html

Comment: Try not to worry about statistical significance. p values are not very useful. Effect sizes are far more important imho. Suppose you have an effect of -5, with a p-value of 0.051, which would not be significant at the 5% level. Compare that with an effect size of -0.1 with a p-value of 0.0499 which would be significant. Let's say it's a study about an intervention to reduce BMI in people with BMI> 30. A reduction of -5 is incredibly meaningful, whereas -0.1 is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I work in scientific research and we care for both substantial and statistical significance. You should not exclude that large effects are due to chance only. This is pretty common in underpowered studies.

Comment: Indeed, which is a good reason for ensuring sufficient power with a sample size calc first. Anyway, I'll see if I can incorporate `ggsignif` into my answer a bit later.